# Alternatives to try/catch in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, try-catch

A coworker alerted me to this handy piece of VBA he found on the web, which unlocks a worksheet in Microsoft Excel without a password:

```
Sub PasswordBreaker()

'Breaks worksheet password protection.

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer

On Error Resume Next

For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
  Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
  Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)

  If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
    MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
    Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
    Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
    Exit Sub
  End If

Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

It works, and it does so very quickly.

We have a VSTO extension to Excel, and we wanted to add this feature.  A near-literal (still discrete looping, no recursion or anything) translation of the code above into C# is as follows:

```
    public static string Unprotect()
    {
        var addIn = Globals.ThisAddIn;
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = addIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

        if (!sheet.ProtectContents)
            return "This sheet was not protected";

        int[] la = new int[] { 65, 66 };

        foreach (int i in la)
            foreach (int j in la)
                foreach (int k in la)
                    foreach (int l in la)
                        foreach (int m in la)
        foreach (int i1 in la)
            foreach (int i2 in la)
                foreach (int i3 in la)
                    foreach (int i4 in la)
                        foreach (int i5 in la)
                            foreach (int i6 in la)
                                for (int n = 32; n <= 126; n++)
        {
            string password = string.Format(
                "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}{7}{8}{9}{10}{11}",
                (char)i, (char)j, (char)k, (char)l, (char)m, 
                (char)i1, (char)i2, (char)i3, (char)i4, (char)i5, 
                (char)i6, (char)n);

            try
            {
                sheet.Unprotect(password);
                if (!sheet.ProtectContents)
                    return password;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        return "Fail.";
    }
```

This works equally successfully, however in cases where it takes a long time to find the password, the VBA solution trounces the C# solution in performance.  The difference can be < 1 second versus 1 1/2 minutes.

I know try-catch is generally an expensive operation, and having to catch every failed attempt is what's dragging performance down.

I'm guessing the Excel VBA's `on error resume next` must be a fairly lightweight operation?

Does anyone know of an alternative to the try-catch in this instance, perhaps an Excel com-specific way to handle this?  In my mind I'm thinking of Int32.TryParse or Dictionary.TryGetValue.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but a question I have is why are you needing to crack passwords in Excel? Is the individual who decided the worksheet needs protection not available?

Comment: The more programmatic question is is that the actual routine with actual values? That is going to generate strings with 11 characters of A or B and then 1 character that is 1 of 95 different values. If the password is not equal to 12 characters in length, that routine won't find it. If it is 12 characters but not of the form ABAAABBAABB#, it won't find it. (Trying to develop a brute force routine for passwords of indeterminate length and a broader range of characters will, of course, be extremely time consuming.)

Comment: Probably caused by the COM-Interop overhead on the Sheet. calls rather than anything specific to Try/Catch

Comment: You could create a VBA add-in with the code, then use VSTO to load it into the Excel instance and run the unlocking routine. Unload the add-in when done.  This would avoid the cross-process slowdown which Charles mentions.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, I was skeptical at first, but it works.  Try it.  If your password is "fish," it might be that AAABAABABAi works to unlocks the spreadsheet.  Some Excel Ninja obviously figured this out.  I've tried dozens of passwords, and it always works.  My guess is behind the scenes, it's sort of like a hashing function.  Also, we are trying to "crack" passwords in Excel because vendors send us spreadsheets with dirty data, and we have to make minor corrections before we upload it.  We can do this with copy/paste before correcting, but that's an extra step each time.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I'm intrigued...  do you have an example?  I didn't know you could mix and match VBA with C#.  As much as I prefer C#, VBA seems to be the de-facto language of MS office, and it would be nice to load in custom functions for purposes in addition to this question.  I've looked at Excel DNA (http://exceldna.codeplex.com/), which looks interesting.

Comment: @Hambone - it's not really mix and match as such, but you can use `Application.Run` from C# to run a VBA macro in Excel (ie. that same macro you list in your question).

Comment: @Hambone one huge improvement on the C# side would be to use LINQ rather than all those loops. The other would be to take advantage of `StringBuilder` class. I agree with Charles that it's the COM that probably slows things down a lot. Like Tim Williams said, you could create an Excel personal workbook and just run the pure VBA from your C# VSTO add-in