# Apply Formatting to Excel Named Range using Office.Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to change the formatting for all Named Ranges in an Excel file but I'm getting an error: "unable to set the name property of the font class".
Sorry if this has been asked but I could not find any.

Here's my code. I'm sure I'm just missing something.

Thanks in advance!

```
            Excel.Application xlsx = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wb = xlsx.Workbooks.Open(filepath, ReadOnly: false, Editable: true);

            foreach (Excel.Name NamedRange in wb.Names)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(NamedRange.Name.ToString());

                NamedRange.RefersToRange.Cells.Font.Name = "Arial";

            }

            xlsx.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
            xlsx.Application.Quit();
            xlsx.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see any error that resembles that one, it probably indicates that either the cell, the worksheet or the workbook itself is protected.  Try to select the range manually (within Excel, not C#) and change the Font.  My guess is you will get a similar error.

There are ways to unprotect within C#, but before heading down that path, evaluate the use case and see if that makes sense for what you are trying to do.

Or, check to see if the range is protected before executing your command.  Something similar to this should work.

```
if (!NamedRange.RefersToRange.Locked)
    NamedRange.RefersToRange.Cells.Font.Name = "Arial";
```

On a side note, Excel has pretty weak protection (by design), there are ways to hack the protection.  Here is one example:

[Alternatives to try/catch in VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434135/alternatives-to-try-catch-in-vsto)

Comment: Thank you Hambone! It was indeed protected